# How to match more regex options in the same Python function, with optional arguments?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, function

I have this Python function:

```
def find_regex(regex, text, opzione2= None, opzione3 = None):
lista = []
for x in text:
    matches_prima = re.findall(regex, x)
    lunghezza1 = len(matches_prima)
    if opzione2 != None and opzione3 == None:
        matches_prima2 = re.findall(opzione2, x)
        lunghezza2 = len(matches_prima2)
        if opzione2 != None and opzione3 != None:
            matches_prima3 = re.findall(opzione3, x)
            lunghezza3 = len(matches_prima3)
lunghezza = len(matches_prima) + len(matches_prima2) + len(matches_prima3)


lista.append(lunghezza)
print("The number of {} matches is ".format(regex), sum(lista))
```

It is supposed to make a sum of all the regex matches in the same text. However, `opzione2` and `opzione3` are optional, I can have more possibilities and include more regex or not. However, this code doesn't work.

It is called like:

One option

```
FIND_FASE12T = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\sT")

find_regex(FIND_FASE12T, testo_fasi)
```

More options

```
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_123FRECCIAT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*T")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*(T|3\sT)")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*(T|3\sT)")

find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T, testo_fasi, FIND_FASE_PRIMA_123FRECCIAT, FIND_FASE_PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong:

```
if opzione2 != None and opzione3 == None:
    # we get here only if opzione3 is None…
    matches_prima2 = re.findall(opzione2, x)
    lunghezza2 = len(matches_prima2)
    # …so there is no way opzione3 is not None HERE:
    if opzione2 != None and opzione3 != None:
        matches_prima3 = re.findall(opzione3, x)
```

You probably want something like that:

```
def find_regex(regex, text, opzione2= None, opzione3 = None):
    lista = []
    for x in text:
        matches_prima = re.findall(regex, x)
        matches_prima2 = []
        matches_prima3 = []
        if opzione2 is not None:
            matches_prima2 = re.findall(opzione2, x)
            if opzione3 is not None:
                matches_prima3 = re.findall(opzione3, x)
        lunghezza = len(matches_prima) + len(matches_prima2) + len(matches_prima3)
        lista.append(lunghezza)
    print("The number of {} matches is ".format(regex), sum(lista))
```

Comment: Thank you! I see there is a problem when there are three options, maybe because regex the first match is not a list and the other two are?

Comment: I mean it finds nothing with three options

Comment: I'd rather suppose you passed wrong regexp as `opzione3`…